# Cold Fusion Shopping Cart not working

Tags: jquery, html, coldfusion

I've spent the last month trying to get this ColdFusion problem to work...I have 5 cfm files. These are the following issues i'm having:
ShoppingCart.cfm : the table is cascading instead of staying the same format.
revieworder.cfm: the customerinfo from the customerinfo.cfm page isn't showing up.
OrderConfirmation.cfm: emailing the customer a copy of the invoice isn't working...frankly the whole thing isn't working and i have a feeling it has something to do with the session: application.cfm file.  if anyone could help guide me with these, i would greatly appreciate it!!

**application.cfc**

```html
<cfcomponent> 
    <cfset this.name = "mmd24shoppingcart"> 
    <cfset this.datasource = "mmd24_shoppingcart">  
    <cfset this.sessionmanagement="Yes"> 
    <cfset this.sessiontimeout="#createtimespan(0,0,45,0)#">
    <cfset This.applicationtimeout="#createtimespan(5,0,0,0)#">
    <cffunction name = "onApplicationStart">
  
    <cfscript>
        Application.availableResources=0;
        Application.counter1=1;
        Application.sessions=0;
    </cfscript>
    </cffunction>
    <cffunction name="onSessionStart">
    <cfscript>
        Session.started = now();
        Session.shoppingCart = Structnew();
        Session.shoppingCart.items =0;
    </cfscript>
    </cffunction>

    </cfcomponent>
```

shoppingcart.cfm

```html
<!doctype html>
    <htmllang="en">

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <head>
    <cfparam name="url.productid" default="">
    <cfparam name="url.qty" default="">

    </head>

    <title>shoppingcart</title>

    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <h3><center>Shopping Cart</center></h3>            
        
        <cfquery name = "getlist" datasource="mmd24_shoppingcart">
           SELECT *
           FROM Products
           WHERE Products.productID = <cfqueryparam  
     cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#url.productid#">
        </cfquery>

     <cflock scope="session" timeout="10">   

                    <cfset addNew = true>

                    <cfif not isDefined("session.cart")>

                       <cfset session.cart = arrayNew(1)>

                    <cfelse>

                       <cfloop index="i" from="1"
     to="#arrayLen(session.cart)#">

                           <cfif URL.productid is session.cart[i].productId>

                               <cfset session.cart[i].productQty =  
    session.cart[i].productQty + 1>

                               <cfset addNew = false>
                           </cfif>
                       </cfloop>

                    </cfif>

                    <cfif addNew is true>

                       <cfset newItem=StructNew()>

                       <cfset newItem.productId = URL.productid>

                       <cfset newItem.productName = getlist.ProductName>

                       <cfset newItem.productPrice = getlist.ProductPrice>

                       <cfset newItem.productDescription = 
    getlist.ProductDescription>

                       <cfset newItem.productQty = URL.qty>

                       <cfset newItem.productPhoto = getlist.ProductPhoto>

                       <cfset ArrayAppend(session.cart, newItem)>

                    </cfif>        
  
  <cfset TotalOrderAmount = 0>
  <cfset TotalItemAmount = 0>
  <cfset TotalTax = 0>
  <cfset counterhi = 0>
    </cflock>

    <cfoutput query ="getlist">

    <cflock scope="session" type="readonly" timeout="10">
        
    <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#arrayLen(session.cart)#">

    <table class = "table table-bordered">
 <thead>
     <tr>
            <th>Product Photo</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Product Description</th>
            <th>Quantity Ordered</th>
            <th>Product Price</th>
          </th>
 </thead> 
    
    <tbody>  
          <tr>
        <td><img src="#session.cart[i].ProductPhoto#"></td>
      <td>#session.cart[i].ProductName#</td>
      <td>#session.cart[i].ProductDescription#</td>
        <td>#session.cart[i].ProductQty#</td>
      <td>#DollarFormat(session.cart[i].ProductPrice)#</td>
         </tr>   
    </tbody>

    <table class = "table">
   <cfset Itemtotal = #getlist.productprice# *  
    #session.cart[i].ProductQty#>
  <cfset OrderTotal = #Itemtotal#>
  <cfset Tax = #OrderTotal# * "0.08">
  <cfset TotalOrderAmount = #OrderTotal# + #Tax# + #TotalOrderAmount#>
  <cfset TotalItemAmount = #Itemtotal# + #TotalItemAmount#>
  <cfset TotalTax = #Tax# + #TotalTax#> 
 <tr>
     <td class="col-lg-9 text-right">Subtotal</td>              
        <td class="text - left">#DollarFormat(itemTotal)#</td>
    </tr>
 
  <tr>               
       <td class="col-lg-9 text-right">Tax(8%)</td>
        <td>#DollarFormat(Tax)#</td>
   
    </tr>
   <tr>               
      <td class="col-lg-9 text-right">Order Total</td>
        <td>#DollarFormat(TotalOrderAmount)#
        <br>
        <br>
        
    </cfloop>
    </cflock>       
    </cfoutput>
        
        <a input type="submit" name="submit" href="customerinfo.cfm" 
    class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Proceed to Checkout</a>
        <br>
        </br>
        <a input type="submit" name="submit" href="productlist.cfm" 
    class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Continue Shopping</a>
        
        </td>
            </tr>               
    </tbody>

          </div>
  
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

customerinfo.cfm

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Customer Info</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Html5TemplatesDreamweaver.com">

    <link href="scripts/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="scripts/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" 
    rel="stylesheet">    
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
   
    </head>
    <body id="pageBody">
    </script>

     
     <table border="3" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;border-
    collapse:collapse;
  border:3px solid #0033FF;color:#000000;">
        
    <tr>
  <td>         
          <div id="divHeaderLine1">Billing Address</div>
          <br>
  <label for="bFirstName"><font color="red">*</font>First Name</label>
        <input type="text" size="20" required="" 
    name="bFirstName" id="bFirstName">
        <br>
  <label for="bLastName"><font color="red">*</font>Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" size="20" required="" 
    name="bLastName">
        <br>
  <label for="bAddress"><font color="red">*</font>Address</label>
        <input type="text" size="20" required="" name="bAddress">
        <br>
  <label for="bCity"><font color="red">*</font>City</label>
        <input type="text" size="20" required="" name="bCity">
        <br>
  <label for="bState"><font color="red">*</font>State</label>
        <select name="bState" size=”4”>
     <option value="" selected></option>
     <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
     <option value="FL">Florida</option>
     <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
     <option value="TX">Texas</option>
     <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
     <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
     </select>
        <br>
  <label for="bZip"><font color="red">*</font>Zip Code</label>
        <input type="text" size="20" required="" name="bZip">
        <br>
  <label for"bEmail"><font color="red">*</font>Email Address</label>
        <input type="text" size="20" name="bEmail">
    </td>

    <td>                  
    <div id="divHeaderLine1">Shipping Address</div>
    <br>
    </br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="billingtoo"   
    onclick="FillBilling(this.form)">Same as billing
    <br>
    <br>
    
    <label for="sFirstName"><font color="red">*</font>First Name</label>
 <input type="text" size="20" name="sFirstName">
       
  <label for="sLastName"><font color="red">*</font>Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" size="20" name="sLastName">
        <br>
  <label for="sAddress"><font color="red">*</font>Address</label>
        <input type="text" size="20" name="sAddress">
        <br>
  <label for="sCity"><font color="red">*</font>City</label>
        <input type="text" size="20" name="sCity">
        <br>
  <label for="sState"><font color="red">*</font>State</label>
        <select name="sState" size=”4”>
     <option value="" selected></option>
     <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
     <option value="FL">Florida</option>
     <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
     <option value="TX">Texas</option>
     <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
     <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
     </select>
        <br>
  <label for="sZip"><font color="red">*</font>Zip Code</label>
        <input type="text" size="20" name="sZip">
        <br>
  <label for="sEmail"><font color="red">*</font>Email Address</label>
        <input type="text" size="20" name="sEmail">
    <br/>
    
    </td>
 </tr>
    
 <tr>
 <td>    
    <div id="divHeaderLine1">Shipping Method</div>
       <br>
                </br>
    <input class="validate[required] checkbox" type="checkbox" 
    name="Shipping" value="OverNight"> Over Night <br/>
    <input class="validate[required] checkbox" type="checkbox" 
    name="Shipping" value="OneDay"> One Day <br/>
    <input class="validate[required] checkbox" type="checkbox" 
    name="Shipping" value="TwoDay" checked> Two Day <br/>
                
                <br>
     </td>
 
     <td> 
     <div id="divHeaderLine1">Payment Details</div>
     <br>
     <br>
                <celect class="cc-ddl-type">
    <input class="validate[required] radio" type="radio" 
    name="CC" value="Visa" checked> Visa <br/>
    <input class="validate[required] radio" type="radio" 
    name="CC" value="Master"> Master <br/>
    <input class="validate[required] radio" type="radio" 
    name="CC" value="Discover"> Discover <br/>
                <br><label><font color="red">*</font> Card Number </label>
     <input value="" class="ccNumber" type="text" required="">
                <br>
  
    <label>Expires on:</label>
                <select name="ccMonth" class="validate[required]">
                    <option value="January">January</option>
                    <option  
    value="February">February</option>
                                            <option 
    value="March">March</option>
                                            <option    
    value="April">April</option>
                                            <option value="May">May</option>
                                            <option    
    value="June">June</option>
                                            <option 
    value="July">July</option>
                                            <option 
    value="August">August</option>
                                            <option 
    value="September">September</option>
                                            <option 
    value="October">October</option>
                                            <option 
    value="November">November</option>
                                            <option 
    value="December">December</option>
                                        </select>
  <br/>
                                        <select name="ccYear"   
    class="validate[required]">
                                            <option 
    value="2011">2016</option>
                                            <option 
    value="2012">2017</option>
                                            <option 
    value="2013">2018</option>
                                            <option 
    value="2014">2019</option>
                                            <option 
    value="2015">2020</option>
                                        </select>
                    
    </td>
    </tr>


                 <br/>
                <br>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
     <a input type="submit" href="revieworder.cfm" class="btn btn-primary" 
     role="button">Review Order</a>               
     </td>
     </tr>
 
     </table>
                
     </form>      
    <script src="scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="scripts/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
    type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

revieworder.cfm

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>revieworder</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <link href="scripts/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="scripts/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css"   
    rel="stylesheet">

    <cfparam name="form.bFirstName" default="">
    <cfparam name="form.bLastName" default="">
    <cfparam name="form.bAddress" default="">
    <cfparam name="form.bCity" default="">
    <cfparam name="form.bState" default="">
    <cfparam name="form.bZip" default="">
    <cfparam name="form.bEmail" default="">

    <cfparam name="form.sFirstName" default="">
    <cfparam name="form.sLastName" default="">
    <cfparam name="form.sAddress" default="">
    <cfparam name="form.sCity" default="">
    <cfparam name="form.sState" default="">
    <cfparam name="form.sZip" default="">
    <cfparam name="form.sEmail" default="">

    <cfparam name="form.ccNumber" default="">
    <cfparam name="form.ccMonth" default="">
    <cfparam name="form.ccYear" default="">
    <cfparam name="form.shipping" default="">
    <cfparam name="form.CC" default="">

    <cfset TotalOrderAmount = 0>
    <cfset TotalItemAmount = 0>
    <cfset TotalTax = 0>
    <cfset ShippingTotal = 0>

    </head>
    <body id="pageBody">
    <form action="OrderConfirmation.cfm" method="post">
    <table border="1" width="100%" align="center">
     <thead>
     <tr>
     <cfoutput>
   <td width="20%">
   Product Photo</td>
   <td width="20%">
   Product Name</td>
   <td width="20%">
   UnitPrice</td>
   <td width="20%">
   Quantity Ordered</td>
   <td width="20%">
   Total Cost</td>
   </td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
   
   <cflock scope="session" type="readonly" timeout="5">
   <cfparam name="session.cart" default="#ArrayNew(1)#">
   <cfset cart = ArrayLen(session.cart)>
   <cfset total = 0>
   <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#cart#">
   <td width="20%">
            
     <cfset Itemtotal = #session.cart[i].ProductPrice# *    
    #session.cart[i].ProductQty#>
     <cfset OrderTotal = #session.cart[i].ProductPrice#>
     <cfset Tax = #OrderTotal# * "0.08">
     <cfset TotalOrderAmount = #OrderTotal# + #Tax# +    
    #TotalItemAmount#>
     <cfset TotalItemAmount = #Itemtotal# >
     <cfset TotalTax = #Tax# + #TotalTax#>
                    <cfif #Shipping# is "Ground">
     <cfset ShippingTotal = .01 * #TotalOrderAmount#>
     </cfif>
     <cfif #Shipping# is "Air">
        <cfset ShippingTotal = .02 * #TotalOrderAmount#>
       </cfif>
      <cfif #Shipping# is "Overnight">
      <cfset ShippingTotal = .03 * #TotalOrderAmount#>
      </cfif>                 
  
    <tr>
     <td colspan="1"><b>
      <img src="#session.cart[i].ProductPhoto#"></b></td>
     <td colspan="1"><b>
      #session.cart[i].ProductName#</b></td> 
     <td colspan="1"><b>
      #session.cart[i].ProductPrice#</b></td>
     <td colspan="1"><b>
      #session.cart[i].ProductQty#</b></td>
     <td colspan="1"><b>
      #session.cart[i].ProductPrice#</b></td>
    </tr>
    </cfloop>
   </cflock> 
   </tr>
   <td colspan="4"><b>
   Order Amount</b></td>
   <td colspan="1"><b>
    <center>#DollarFormat(TotalItemAmount)#</center></td>   
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td colspan="4"><b>
    Tax</b></td>
   <td colspan="1"><b>
    <center>#DollarFormat(TotalTax)#</center></td>  
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td colspan="4"><b>
    Shipping Cost </b></td>
   <td colspan="1"><b>
    <center>#DollarFormat(ShippingTotal)#</center></td>  
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td colspan="4"><b>
    Order Total</b></td>
   <td colspan="1"><b>
    <cfset TotalOrderAmount =  + #TotalOrderAmount#>
    <center>#DollarFormat(TotalOrderAmount)#</center></td>  
   </tr>
   </cfoutput>
  </thead>
   </table>
 
      <div id="divHeaderText" class="page-content">    
     <div id="divHeaderLine1">Your Address and Payment Details</div>
      </br> 
                    
    <table border="1" width="75%" align="center">
  <tr>
     <cfoutput>
       
    <td><b>Billing Address:</td></b> 
    <td width="80%">
    #Form.bFirstName# #Form.bLastName#<br>
    #Form.bAddress# <br>
    #Form.bCity#, #Form.bState# #Form.bZip#<br>
    <strong>Email: </strong>#Form.bEmail#<br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><b>Shipping Address:</b></td>
    <td>
    #form.sFirstName# #form.sLastName# <br>
    #form.sAddress#<br>
    #form.sCity#, #form.sState# #form.sZip#<br>
    <b>Email: </b>#form.sEmail#<br>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><b>Payment Type:</td> </b><br><td>
   #form.CC# Credit Card Number: #REReplace(form.ccNumber," 
            [0-9](?=.*.{4})", "*", "all")#  <br>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <b>Exp Date: </b></td><td>#form.ccMonth# /#form.ccYear#
    </td>
    </td>
   </tr>
        </cfoutput>
     </thead>
     </table>
     

   <br><br><br><br>
     <input type="hidden" name="Email" value="<cfoutput>#form.bEmail# 
    </cfoutput>"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="ShippingA" value="<cfoutput>#ShippingTotal#
    </cfoutput>"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="OrderA" value="<cfoutput>#TotalOrderAmount#
    </cfoutput>"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="ItemA" value="<cfoutput>#TotalItemAmount#
    </cfoutput>"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="TaxA" value="<cfoutput>#TotalTax#
    </cfoutput>"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="Address" value="<cfoutput>#form.bAddress#  
    </cfoutput>"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="Shipping" value="<cfoutput>#form.Shipping#  
    </cfoutput>"/> 
   <a input type="submit" value="submit" href="OrderConfirmation.cfm"  
    class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Confirm Order</a>

   </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Order Confirmation.cfm (this is where everything is all messed up)

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Order Confirmation</title>
    <cfparam name="form.email" default="VOID">
    <cfparam name="form.Shipping" default="">
    <cfparam name="form.address" default="">
    <cfparam name="form.ShippingA" default="0">
    <cfparam name="form.OrderA" default="0">
    <cfparam name="form.ItemA" default="0">
    <cfparam name="form.TaxA" default="0">

    Email Confirmation
    <cfmail from="mmd24@students.uwf.edu" to="#form.email#" subject="Your  
    Order Confirmation" type="html">
    <html>        
     <head></head>        
     <body>                  
    <cfset r = randomize(7, "SHA1PRNG")> 
    <cfset Int = 10000 /> 
     <cfset Int2 = 80000 /> 
    <cfoutput>
    Thank you for your Order #session.customerform.BfirstName#    
    #session.customerform.BlastName#</br>
    Your order numer is #randRange(Int, Int2, "SHA1PRNG")# </br>
    <cfif #session.customerform.Shipping# is "OverNight">
       Your order will arive in 12 Hours since you opted   
    for Over Night shipping
       </cfif>
        <cfif #session.customerform.Shipping# is "OneDay">
       Your order will arive in 1 day since you opted for One 
      Day shipping
       </cfif>
       <cfif #session.customerform.Shipping# is "TwoDay">
       Your order will arive in 2 days since you opted for 
      Two Day shipping
       </cfif></br>
     Your order will be shipped to the following address:   
     #session.customerform.address#

     <table border="1" width="100%" align="center">
     <thead>
     <tr>
   <th colspan="5">
    Your Order Details
    </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <cfoutput>
     <td width="20%">
     Product Photo</td>
     <td width="20%">
     Product Name</td>
     <td width="20%">
     UnitPrice</td>
     <td width="20%">
     Quantity Ordered</td>
     <td width="20%">
     Total Cost</td>
     </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
   
     <cflock scope="session" type="readonly" timeout="5">
     <cfparam name="session.cart" default="#ArrayNew(1)#">
     <cfset cart = ArrayLen(session.cart)>
     <cfset total = 0>
     <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#cartSize#">
     <td width="20%">
     <tr>
      <td colspan="1"><b>
       <img src="#session.cart[i].ProductPhoto#"></b></td>
      <td colspan="1"><b>
       #session.cart[i].ProductName#</b></td> 
      <td colspan="1"><b>
       #session.cart[i].ProductPrice#</b></td>
      <td colspan="1"><b>
      #session.cart[i].ProductQTY#</b></td>
      <td colspan="1"><b>
       #session.cart[i].ProductPrice#</b></td>
     </tr>
    </cfloop>
    </cflock> 
      </tr>
   <td colspan="4"><b>
      Order Amount</b></td>
    <td colspan="1"><b>
    <center>#DollarFormat(form.ItemA)#</center></td>   
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="4"><b>
     Tax</b></td>
    <td colspan="1"><b>
     <center>#DollarFormat(form.TaxA)#</center></td>  
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="4"><b>
     Shipping Cost (Shipping Method: #session.customerform.Shipping#) 
      </b></td>
    <td colspan="1"><b>
     <center>#DollarFormat(form.ShippingA)#</center></td>  
    </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="4"><b>
     Order Total</b></td>
   <td colspan="1"><b>
     <center>#DollarFormat(form.OrderA)#</center></td>  
   </tr>
    </cfoutput>
    </thead>
    </table>          
      </cfoutput>
      </body>  
      </html>
      </cfmail>
      </head>

      <cflock scope="session" timeout="10">

    <cfset session.customerform = StructNew()>

    <cfset session.customerform.bFirstName = form.bFirstName>
    <cfset session.customerform.bLastName = form.bFastName>
    <cfset session.customerform.bAddress = form.bAddress>
    <cfset session.customerform.bCity = form.bCity>
    <cfset session.customerform.bCtate = Form.bState>
    <cfset session.customerform.bZipCode = Form.bZipCode>
    <cfset session.customerform.bEmail = Form.bEmail>

    <cfset session.customerform.sFirstName = Form.sFirstName>
    <cfset session.customerform.sLastName = Form.sLastName>
    <cfset session.customerform.sAddress = Form.sAddress>
    <cfset session.customerform.sCity = Form.sCity>
    <cfset session.customerform.sState = Form.sState>
    <cfset session.customerform.sZipCode = Form.sZipCode>
    <cfset session.customerform.sEmail = Form.sEmail>

    <cfset session.customerform.CC = Form.CC>
    <cfset session.customerform.ccMonth = Form.ccMonth>
    <cfset session.customerform.ccYear = Form.ccYear>
    <cfset session.customerform.Shipping= Form.Shipping>

    </cflock>
    
    <div id="divHeaderText" class="page-content">
                    <div id="divHeaderLine1">Thank you for your Order </div>
     
     #session.customerform.bFirstName#  
    #session.customerform.bLastName# !!</div>
                    <h2>Your Order number is <font color="red"> 
    #randRange(Int, Int2, "SHA1PRNG")# </font></h2>
                    <h2><cfif #session.customerform.Shipping# is "OverNight">
      Your order will arive in 12 hours since you opted for   
     Overnight shipping
        </cfif>
       <cfif #session.customerform.Shipping# is "OneDay">
      Your order will arive in 1 day since you opted for One 
     Day shipping
       </cfif>
      <cfif #session.customerform.Shipping# is "TwoDay">
      Your order will arive in 2 days since you opted for Two 
    Day shipping
       </cfif></h2>
    <h2>Your order will be shipped to the following address: <font  
    color="red">#session.customerform.sAddress# </font></h2>
                    
     </br>                              
                </div>

    <cflock timeout=20 scope="Session" type="Exclusive">
    <cfset StructDelete(Session, "cart")>
    </cflock>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: nice, now post the database and we have a complete app, seriously can't you just post only the relevant code?

Comment: Had a quick look: application.cfc looks OK. shopping.cfm, you need to loop over the rows in tbody, not the whole table. The rest of it is just too hard to try and trawl through as commented above. Also, which version of CF are you developing on as your code could be modernized alot to make it much easier to read / develop.

Comment: Pick one issue and solve it.  See if the other issues go away.

Comment: madalin there's no need to be rude, i'm asking for help...smh...

Comment: John, thank you and i will attempt to fix now. i'm using coldfusion 10.  my main issue is the the customer form and why the input variables aren't passing into the revieworder page. i'm still fairly new with coldfusion. if i can figure out least how to get customer info passed onto review order, then the last page should be easy....

Comment: @WTFVet79 - While we can all appreciate the frustration, unfortunately that is too much code for most folks to wade through. You need to narrow it down. Start from scratch and put together a [*small*, stand-alone, example with a few fields](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Do not include the kitchen sink ;-)  The more code and moving pieces there are, the harder it will be for you, or anyone else, to troubleshoot. Only include the absolute *minimum* code necessary to reproduce a single issue.

Answer (score 0):

Had a quick look and clearly there are two issues with 'customerinfo.cfm':

1. There is no starting `<form>` tag. Though there is a closing tag: `</form>`.
2. The syntax of the SUBMIT button is wrong.

Insert a starting `<form>` tag and define the form action as "reviewOrder.cfm". Change the submit button to `<input type="submit ...>`

One more thing: end of script tag (`</script>`) is appearing after start of body tag!

Hope this will help!